# How to get username using System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName in asp.net core web application?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

There is no login page in my application and I am trying to get the current user name of the web application on both windows and Linux servers.

Here is what I tried

[retuned items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C30sy.png)

```
        var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

        string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });

        var getuserid = computer_name[0].ToString();
```

As you can see in this image  `computer_name` returns `[0] computername, [1] myurl ,[2] com` after splitting .But I can not get my username in returned array.

I also tried `this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` but it returns null value .

I am using this code in my `controller` .

Any hep appreciated .

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "username". You can't get a human's username that way. And even the computer name will not be accessible if the client is behind any kind of gateway.

Comment: Enviorenment.UserName gives you username for e.g DOE_J but this is not working on Linux so I tried above way to make it work on both.If there is any helpful link please share so that I can try it out as well.

Comment: `Environment.UserName` is only going to work when you are running the site on your own computer. On a server the site is running as a service identity and you will always get only that identity. You cannot get the username of a person using your site if you do not have users sign in.